# rails 2 undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web

I use rails v 2.3.14

I add route in `routes.rb`

```
  map.with_options :controller => 'consumer_profile' do |m|
   ...
    m.consumer_profile_show_coupons 'consumer/:id/coupons', :action => 'show_coupons', :requirements => {:id => /c-[0-9a-zA-Z]+/}
   ...
  end
```

I add def in `consumer_profile_controller.rb`

```
  def show_coupons
    ..
  end
```

I add file `consumer_profile/show_coupons.html.erb`
rake routes:

```
consumer_profile_show_coupons      /consumer/:id/coupons                                                                               {:action=>"show_coupons", :controller=>"consumer_profile"}
```

but when I use `seo_consumer_profile_coupons_url(current_user.consumer_profile)`
that rails says:

```
undefined method `seo_consumer_profile_coupons_url'
```

Have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pointed out the direct `:controller=>'consumer_profile',:action=>'show_coupons'` in `link_to`, it works...